# Inserting DateTime into SQL Server CE database via VB.NET

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert into a database using the code below, however, every time I get an error:

> There was a syntax error in the date format. [ Expression = @DOB ]

I have tried pretty much every date format available, tolongdate, toshortdate etc & no matter what I use this error shows.

The database column format is `datetime`. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
' Insert New User - Create Connection
Dim sqlConn As New SqlCeConnection(My.Settings.CompDbConnectionString)

' Open Connection
sqlConn.Open()

' Query DB
Dim sqlComm As New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Profiles(Title, FirstName, LastName, DOB) VALUES(@Title, '@FirstName', '@LastName', '@DOB')", sqlConn)

' Add Parameters
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = ComboTitle.SelectedItem.ToString()
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = txtFirstName.Text
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = txtLastName.Text
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DteDOB.Value.ToUniversalTime

' Insert Into Database
Try
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Failed To Update Your Details:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try

' Close Connection
sqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: In this code `VALUES(@Title, '@FirstName', '@LastName', '@DOB')` try removing the apostrophes

Answer (score 5):

Try killing the apostrophies:

> INSERT INTO Profiles(Title, FirstName, LastName, DOB) 
>     VALUES (@Title, '@FirstName', '@LastName', '@DOB')

should be just:

> INSERT INTO Profiles(Title, FirstName, LastName, DOB) 
>     VALUES (@Title, @FirstName, @LastName, @DOB)

Comment: You beat me to it!  Didn't notice before I posted my answer.

Comment: @Jim tcarvin's comment beat me as well.

Comment: Damn, for some reason I thought this was best practive. Will approve your answer in 5 mins when I am allowed to! Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @Chris Parameters are definitely best practice (to avoid sql injection), but by adding the single quotes to the sql, it turned the parameters into a text and your database was looking for a date type.

Answer (score 0):

Take the single quotes out from the @DOB in the INSERT statement.  They aren't needed.